# Clion compiler error during the builduing process

Tags: c++, class, g++, mingw, clion

I trying to make a simple classes [program](http://pastebin.com/LJqRWsS7), but I get a strange error, from what I see it's not the issue with the code but something with the Clion.

```
CMakeFiles\Assignment_4.dir/objects.a(Box.cpp.obj):Box.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Box::objectCount'
CMakeFiles\Assignment_4.dir/objects.a(Q_1.cpp.obj):Q_1.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Assignment_4.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Assignment_4.dir\build.make:147: recipe for target 'Assignment_4.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Assignment_4.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Assignment_4.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Assignment_4.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Assignment_4.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Assignment_4] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Assignment_4' failed
```

Even when compiling directly with g++ I multiple object definition error. It worked before in visual studio.

```
C:\Users\fsa\CLionProjects\McMaster\Assignment_4>g++ Q_1.cpp clock.cpp box.cpp -o Q1.exe
C:\Users\fsa\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmD1R6t.o:box.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Box::objectCount'
C:\Users\fsa\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0nh7LU.o:Q_1.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I was compiling with the wrong command. It should be `g++ Q_1.cpp clock.cpp box.cpp -o Q1.exe`

Comment: So, does it compile successfully now?

Comment: @GigaRohan No, but it  did change the error output. Before my class files weren't compiling at all. Now I have `multiple definition of `Box::objectCount'` error. I going though the code to see the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `int Box::objectCount = 0;` is in the header. So it appears in multiple compilation units (Q1.o and Box.o). It should be be moved to the Box.cpp.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. But, does the placement of the line effect the counter function, because my counter stays at 0 even though 2 box objects are created in main().

Comment: I don't think that matters but usually it would be placed below the header includes in the CPP file. If you still have the issue, I'd say step through your code using a debugger to see what's happening. A side note: `objectCount` should be private in your case.